How to make this kind of "bumpy" mesh to model without Sculpting?
I wanna make a table with this texture (image)
Actually its not a texture, its mesh. How can i get this result without sculpting ?
Like handmade*


It is exactly a Voronoi texture stretched along one axis. What is your question precisely ? You could use a Displace modifier for example.

Do you truly need the geometry to be real? If this isn’t going to be 3-D printed, you probably don’t.

Yeah,i am gonna print it in 3d. Thanks for advice! Gonna try Voronoi !

I did this in Cycles but I think it works in Eevee too.


Add a Plane and subdivide it several times.
Add a Displace modifier.
Click the New button and click the little switches icon Show Texture in Texture Panel. This should take you to the Textures tab with the texture you have selected. Open.
Inside the Textures tab in the Properties panel, choose Voronoi as type.
Adjust the values inside the Voronoi and Feature Weights to achieve the appearance you are after. You will need to scale the plane on the x or y direction to achieve the elongated divots.
Once you have the look, duplicate your mesh.
With the duplicate selected under Object in Object mode, select Apply > Visual Geometry to Mesh.
Apply the scale and export to .stl.

